# How to model one way one-to-one relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to model an article with revisions in Django:

I have following in my article's models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class ArticleRevision(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    revision_nr = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
```

On the artlcle model I want to have 2 direct references to a revision - one would point to a published revision and another to a revision that is being actively edited. However from what I understand, OneToOne and ForeignKey references generate a backreference on the other side of the model reference, so my question is, how do i create a one-way one-to-one reference in Django?

Is there some special incantation for that or do I have to fake it by including state into revision and custom implementations of the fields that ask for a revision in specific state?

**Edit:** I guess, I've done somewhat poor job of explaining my intent. Let's try it on a higher abstraction level:

My original intent was to implement a sort of revisioned article model, where each article may have multiple revisions, where one of those revisions may be "published" and one actively edited.

This means that the article will have one-to-many relationship to revisions (represented by `ForeignKey(Article)` reference in *ArticleRevision* class) and two one way references from Article to revision: *`published_revision`* and *`edited_revision`*.

My question is mainly, how can I model this with Django's ORM.

Comment: Not really an answer, but there are already a couple solutions for versioning Django models, e.g. django-reversion (http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion) or AuditTrail (http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail). Maybe one of them fits your needs and you don't have to reinvent the wheel :-)

Comment: I do not want automatic versioning of my models (that is what these two do). What I am looking for is more of a "manual" revisioning, where an article revision _is_ an article until it gets published. Any edits to a published article will create a new revision. Publishing the new revision will lock this revision and set it up as published revision and next edit on the article will repeat the edit-publish cycle anew (I personally believe that this is much more manageable scheme for regular users than "every edit is a revision" approach).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The back-references that Django produces are programatic, and do not affect the underlying Database schema. In other words, if you have a one-to-one or foreign key field on your Article pointing to your Revision, a column will be added to the Article table in the database, but not to the Revision table.

Thus, removing the reverse relationship from the revision to the article is unnecessary. If you really feel strongly about it, and want to document in your code that the backlink is never used, a fairly common Django idiom is to give the fields a related_name attribute like `_unused_1`. So your Article model might look like the following:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)
    revision_1 = models.OneToOneField(ArticleRevision, related_name='_unused_1')
    revision_2 = models.OneToOneField(ArticleRevision, related_name='_unused_2')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

That said, it's rare that a one-to-one relationship is actually useful in an application (unless you're optimizing for some reason) and I'd suggest carefully reviewing your DB schema to make sure this is really what you want. It may make sense to keep a single ForeignKey field on your ArticleRevision pointing back to an Article (since an ArticleRevision will, presumably, always need to be associated with an Article) and adding another column to Revision indicating whether it's published.

Comment: One-to-one relationship is useful indeed, but in my case, the back-reference should already exist in the form of article-revisions reference and the additional references are just to mark direct references to currently published revision and currently edited revision.

Comment: Since Django 1.2, related_name='+' will result in no backwards relation being available.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with the link going both ways?  I would think that the [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) would be the perfect choice here.  Is there a specific reason why this will be a detriment to your application?  If you don't need the backreference why can't you just ignore it?

Comment: A related_name argument will resolve any problems with the tables if you're going to need to point to two different ArticleRevision models. This would be my answer.